# CodeIgniter remove index.php multiple domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

i have 2 domain names but single server. so i park this two domain names into single server and i need to remove index.php

i have **sample.com** & **sample.co.uk** domains

if single domain means i create a htaccess like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

its working fine in single domain. But when i point 2 domain names in single server means 1 domain working fine. another domain not working.

**I need to remove index.php in different domains using 1 htacccess** please help me any one..

Comment: you mean to say, both of your domain are pointing out single directory or root folder?

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com on my root folder

Comment: @ManishJangirBlogaddition.com 2 domain names are pointing into same website. so only i go this issue

Comment: any one please help me

Comment: @NathanSrivi what is your hosting server?

Comment: It is not depend on how many domain park in your server. You can park as many domain as you need. You need to share the directory structure of your server. And for some hosting server you need to use different .htaccess file.

Comment: My home page working fine in com and co.uk domains. when i put index.php all are working fine. but i need to remove the index.php in codeigniter

Comment: @Arif its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Now i got your problem. You are using godaddy hosting server. So you need to use the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hope it will help you.